# Gibt es den Ausdruck "verodern/verodert"?

Tags: word-choice, technical-terminology

Ich habe diesen Ausdruck `return ( a | func() )` aus einer Programmiersprache.

Ich möchte sagen, dass die Funktion func() ausgeführt wird und das Ergebnis mit dem jetzigen Ergebnis (a) "verodert" und dann zurückgegeben wird.

**Wie formuliere ich das richtig?**

Comment: Genau so. In der Informatik ist "verodern" ein gängiger Begriff. "Verunden" aber übrigens nicht :-)

Comment: Ich kenne es sogar als *Operatoren unden / odern*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Verunden geht genauso, würde ich sagen. Ängstlichen Naturen kann man Und-Verknüpfen oder Oder-Verknüpfen anraten.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ja, der Ausdruck "verodern" existiert und ist *in diesem Kontext* korrekt.

Ob er *schön* ist, ist eine ganz andere Frage... Meist kann man ihn umgehen, indem man den Satz umstellt, hier z.B.:

> ...a wird mit dem Rückgabewert von func() ODER-verknüpft/OR-verknüpft und zurückgegeben.

(Die Großschreibung ist in der Digitaltechnik üblich um auf die [logische Funktion](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunktion) zu verweisen. Korrekter ist die Schreibweise "Oder-Verknüpfung". )

Im Fließtext kann man auch dem Begriff "nicht-ausschließende Disjunktion" verwenden, aber ich kenne genug Informatiker, die den Begriff nicht kennen. Andererseits: warum nicht...?

Comment: Warum ja? Weil Du ihn verwendest?

Comment: @miracle173 - weil eine ganze Branche ihn verwendet...

Comment: Ich arbeite seit 8 Jahren in der IT (als Software Entwickler) und habe verodern bis heute noch nie gelesen oder gehöhrt. Meine Kollegen und ich verwenden üblicherweise OR-verknüpfen.

Comment: Gemäss Duden gibts das Wort eindeutig nicht, aber in der Informatik hab ich sowohl verodern als auch verunden schon öfters gehört. Die Informatiker/Logiker sind da wohl ihrer Zeit voraus. Für den mündlichen Gebrauch sind die Begriffe praktisch, in einer Arbeit bzw. im Geschriebenen würde ich darauf verzichten und einen offizellen Begriff verwenden.

Comment: In deinem Fall wird beim ausführen der Funktion func() jeweils a und func() disjunktiv ausgegeben.

Answer (score 5):

Als Logiker und als Programmierer hab ich das Verb *verodern* (und ebenso das duale *verunden*) immer mal wieder gehört und in gesprochener Sprache sicher auch gelegentlich selbst benutzt. Ich würde es aber eindeutig als *umgangssprachliche* Fachsprache einordnen, obwohl es zweifellos oft die beste und klarste Art ist, einen entsprechenden Sachverhalt auszudrücken. In einer internen Programmdokumentation oder in einem Beweisentwurf würde ich das Verb auch mal schreiben, wenn es sich anbietet. Für eine Endfassung zur Veröffentlichung würde ich dann aber auf jeden Fall eine andere (evt. umständlichere) Formulierung suchen, die das Verb vermeidet. Für ein Logiker-Publikum würde sich im einfachsten Fall *disjunktiv verknüpfen* anbieten, für Programmierer eher *oder-verknüpfen*. Noch besser dürfte aber meist eine ganz andere Formulierung sein.

Comment: *oder-verknüpfen* war im vorletzten Satz gemeint, vermute ich mal. Ansonsten geht es ganz schön durcheinander.

Answer (score 3):

Dass es den Ausdruck gibt, ergibt sich schon daraus, dass er hier auf dieser Seite steht. Damit gibt es ihn.

Zumindest im Suchergebnis von Google.

Diese Seite ist nämlich die erste Eintrag den Google zurück gibt (abgefragt am 17.12.2015) , wenn man wie in der [Antwort von Veredomon](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/20104/1525)  "verodern" in [Google](https://www.google.de/#q=verodern) eingibt.

Der zweite Eintrag ist ein Link auf das [Synonymwörterbuch Woxikon](http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/verodern.php) der besagt, dass dort dieses Wort dort nicht zu finden ist.

Der  dritte Eintrag geht zum [Wörterbuch/Suchmaschine Linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/verodert.html). Da werden mehre Seiten aus dem Internet verglichen, bei denen es offensichtlich englische und deutsche Version gibt. Hier wird im deutschen "verodern" und im Englischen das Verb "or" verwendet (in den Formen "ored", "oring").  Das deutsche Wort "verodern" ist im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/verodern) nicht zu finden, das englische Wort "or" nicht als Verb  im [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/or).

Im vierten Ergebnis,  einen Links zu einem [Leo-Forum](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=187049&idForum=1&lp=ende&lang=en), scherzt ein Poster, "verodern" ist möglicherweise vom Fluss Oder abgeleitet und spricht von der "Veroderung der Elbe", was immer das auch bedeuten soll.

Eine Suche in Büchern die zwischen 1800 und 2008 erschienen sind  mit [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verodern&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) ergibt keine Treffer für "verodern".

Ich würde mich aber nach der Empfehlung eines Posters in der Diskussion des [fünften Suchergebnisses](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/11200#74020) halten:

> Bitte sagt nicht verunden und verodern, denn dann
>   bekommt man echte Probleme bei den folgenden logischen Verknüpfungen :
>    - XOR -> "exklusiv verodern" ? "verexklusivodern" ??
>    - NOT -> "vernichten" ?

Comment: NOT ist ja wohl verneinen. XOR ist auch kein englisches Wort, sondern nur ein Schlüsselwort in manchen Sprachen oder ein Fachausdruck von Experten. Wenn dieser Kontext klar ist und beim Leser als bekannt vorausgesetzt werden kann, kann man auch XOR-en bilden. "Wenn ich A und B XORe erhalte ich ..." wäre eine unproblematische Ausdrucksweise zwischen 2 Programmierern dieser Sprachen.

Comment: @user wenn man bei NOT wie bei OR vorgeht, kommt man zu "vernichten" und nicht zu "verneinen".
Ich gehe davon aus, das bei entsprechender Fachkenntnis auch "exklusiv verodern" und  "verexklusivodern" verstanden wird. "XORe" wird wohl nur verstanden, wenn es geschrieben in dieser Form vorliegt. Setzt man das in die Vergangenheit und verwendet die für Verben übliche Kleinschreibung wird es vermutlich schon ziemlich problematisch "ich habe die Variablen gexort".

Comment: Gexort würde man geksohrt sprechen. Um es Ge-X-ORt zu sprechen müsste man es gehixohrt oder so schreiben. Oder mit einem Bindestrichhagel ge-x-or-t.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt den Ausdruck:

https://www.google.de/#q=verodern

Hört sich aber doch sehr speziell an.

Comment: Kommt auf die Umgebung an. Bei mir im Informatikstudium ist der Begriff durchaus geläufig.

Comment: Nicht spezieller als "Enthaaren".

Comment: Bitte vermerke, dass "verodern" sehr umgangssprachlich ist. In Fachbüchern wird auf schriftsprachlichem Niveau "ODER-verknüpfen" verwendet.

Comment: Informatikstudium kann man wohl als "speziell" ansehen, es ist eben kein Bestandteil des allgemeinen Wortschatzes.